# Highcharts - display dates in heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I there any easy way to load the data in the heatmap with dates on "Y".

My data is in the following format:

```
[{x:1, y: 1401292253, value:0.2, name:"a"},{x:2, y: 1401173762, value:0.3, name:"b"},{x:0, y: 1401173462 , value:0.6, name:"c"}]
```

I want Y of the heatmap to be build automatically based on the given value. But I cant figure out how to do it.

What I've tried is:
http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6GP/16/

Comment: I do not think this is possible in the HC heatmaps. You need send it the matrix coordinates like [0, 0, <value>]. Which seems like this would make sense. However I think you can do it with some trickery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `rowsize` (or `colsize` for xAxis) to tell highcharts what is the range for each point. Otherwise it will be 1ms which is really low value. Second thing is that your y-values are in seconds, while in JS timestamps are in ms.

When changed that two things, you will get nice chart: http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6GP/19/

```
    series: [{
        rowsize: 3600000, // one hour
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 1401292253000,
            value: 0.2,
            name: "a"
        }, {
            x: 1,
            y: 1401173762000,
            value: 0.3,
            name: "b"
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 1401173462000,
            value: 0.6,
            name: "c"
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: thanks, and btw, is it possible for "x-axis category typed" set x-es automatically based on the category "name", e.g. "a" = 0, "b" = 1, "c" = 2? - so I dont want to manually count x-es by myself

Comment: Unfortunatetly, you need to set for each point: x = category_index.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to treat your `yAxis` as categories still but then apply a `label.format`. This should get you started:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: ['a', 'b', 'c']
},

yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: ['1401292253', '1401173762', '1401173462'],
    labels: {
            format: '{value: %H:%M:%S}'
        }
}
```

I also cleaned up your `series.data` a bit. Basically you need to give the matrix coordinates (x/y) and the value.

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        x: 1,
        y: 0,
        value: 0.2
    }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 1,
        value: 0.3
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 2,
        value: 0.6
    }]
}]
```

By looking at this you can make out the locations of your points.

Live **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/tZ6GP/18/)**.

Update for latest highcarts code. You need to modify the yAxis label formatter:

```
yAxis: {
    categories: ['1401292253', '1401173762', '1401173462'],
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
                            var theTime = parseFloat(this.value);
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', theTime);
        }
    }
},
```

Update live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/79sLzcb8/).

Comment: @VISHALDAGA, well, this was an answer from over 4 years ago. A lot has changed in the highhcarts library. Looks like the yAxis.label format is not working in new version like it did when this was written 4 years ago.

Comment: Hi VISHAL DAGA , the solution above works with older Highcharts versions: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xbmd5ku9/